# Counting elements of a list in a predicate

Tags: prolog

I have something like this:

```
plane(1, 2, aaa, b([1,2,3,4]), 3).
```

I'm able to access the elements of plane and show it just like above, but the problem is `b([1,2,3,4])`.
How can I access it to count the number of elements that is inside of that list?

Comment: is the format of `plane` always the same?

Comment: The format of plane is: plane(Id, Id2, name, listofIds, number).

Comment: You can not use directly?: plane(1, 2, aaa, [1,2,3,4], 3).

Comment: If counting the elements of that list is a frequent operation, consider changing your representation to cache that count by e.g. going from `b(List)` to `b(N, List)`. This should be easy if the list is incrementally constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have unified the parameter number 4 with variable `B_list`. If you would like to take the list from inside it, use unification operator `=`, like this:

```
/* Let's pretend that you do not need other parameters */
plane(_, _, _, B_list, _) :-
    /* This assigns the content of the list inside b(...) to List */
    B_list = b(List),
    length(List, N),
    write(N),
    nl.
```

This will print 4.

Comment: plane is, in the original question, a fact, not a rule.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui I wasn't too clear on what the OP is trying to do in the grand scheme of things, so I think my answer is doing it from the inside out. On the other hand, it looks like the answer has solved OP's problem, which is the important thing to me.

Comment: ... but putting write into the definition makes the program very difficult to test...

Comment: @false That's true. However, this whole code snippet is a throw-away code written to show how its 4-th line, `B_list = b(List)`, "pulls" the list into a separate variable, which I think was the obstacle on OP's way to solving a bigger problem. I do agree that rules with side effects are much harder to test.

Comment: It makes understanding the entire point of relations more difficult by at least one further step.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291966/how-to-deal-with-coding-style-activism-on-the-site?s=14|0.0897)

Answer (score 2):

If the format of these `plane`s are always the same, then you can just pattern match (unify) that to bind the list in `b` to a variable, and then check the length (usage `count_in_plane(+,-)`, i.e., provide `P`, get `L`):

```
count_in_plane(P, L) :- 
    P = plane(_,_,_, b(List), _),
    length(List, L).
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, like:

```
count( plane(_,_,_, b(List), _), R ) :- length(List, R).
```